# GitLab CI clones project in pipeline and jobs randomly

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have my own gilab server wit gitlab runner (separate VMs).

my config is:

```yaml
image: miroff/php7.4-tests:latest

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - vendor/

stages:
  - build
  - deploy


build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - php init --env=Production --overwrite=y
    - composer install  -o --no-interaction --no-ansi --prefer-dist


deploy_production:
  image: ubuntu:18.04
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -qq git
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - ssh proj@*.*.* "cd /var/www/proj && git checkout master && git pull origin master && $(which php) /var/www/proj/init --env=Production --overwrite=y && $(which php) /var/www/proj/yii migrate --interactive=0 && exit"
  only:
    - master
```

And I get fails (randomly) on jobs build or deploy

[Error on build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zLos.png)

[Error on deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGg1q.png)

BUT! If I will hit button "retry" it works as a charm.

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: have you only one runner ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster yes